# HDInsight persistent Hive settings

Tags: azure, hive, azure-hdinsight

Every few days the Azure HDInsight cluster is being (randomly?) restarted by Microsoft, and in the process any custom changes to hive-site.xml (such as adding a JsonSerde) are lost without any prior warning, and as a result the hive queries from Excel/PowerPivot starts breaking.

How are you supposed to deal with this scenario - are we forced to store our data as CSV files ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to preserve customization during os update or node re-image, you should think of using script action. Here is the link: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-customize-cluster/

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the Hive config parameter with a custom configuration object at the time of cluster creation, it should persist. The link here http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PowerShell%20Cmdlets%20for%20Cluster%20Management has some more details on creating a cluster with custom configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post on MSDN has a table showing what customizations are supported via the different methods, as well as examples for using PowerShell or the SDK to create a cluster with custom Hive configuration parameters (Line 62-64 in the Powershell example): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/04/15/customizing-hdinsight-cluster-provisioning-via-powershell-and-net-sdk.aspx

This is the only way to persist these settings because the cluster nodes can be reset for Azure servicing events such as security updates, and the configurations are set back to the initial values when this occurs.